# DBAction(parse.json).async with play-slick

Tags: asynchronous, playframework-2.3, play-slick

I am using play-slick. I am trying to trying to return a future within a play-slick DBaction, but I fail:

```
def test = DBAction(parse.json){ implicit request =>
      scala.concurrent.Future {
        NotFound(Json.obj("error" -> "some error"))
      } 
}

[error]  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result]
[error]  required: play.api.mvc.Result
```

How do I return this future? Async { } is gone now in 2.3, and DBAction().async (as the documentation says to use for a normal play-Action with a future) seems not to be available.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this same question / issue since I use Future.firstCompleteOf(*DB call*, *timeout*) and what seems to work for me is to use DB.withSession instead.

So my controller action still stays within an Action.async block and then my Future looks like

```
Future.firstCompleteOf(Seq(Future( 
    DB.withSession {implicit session => MyTable.findById(id) } ), timeoutFuture) ).map { 
      case Whatever => … 
}.recoverWith {
  case Whatever => … 
}
```